# Firebase Remote Config - cannot find symbol

Tags: android, firebase

Trying to build the android app in android studio.

but i get this 2 error, and dont now how to fix them..

```
app\src\main\java\com\xxxxxx\user\UserApplication.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);
                            ^
symbol:   method setDefaults(Map<String,Object>)
location: variable firebaseRemoteConfig of type FirebaseRemoteConfig

app\src\main\java\com\xxxxxxx\user\UserApplication.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                                                ^
symbol:   method activateFetched()
location: variable firebaseRemoteConfig of type FirebaseRemoteConfig
```

I hope someone kind soul can help me.

My code in UserApplication.java

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
        //initCalligraphyConfig();


        final FirebaseRemoteConfig firebaseRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();

        // set in-app defaults
        Map<String, Object> remoteConfigDefaults = new HashMap();
        remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_REQUIRED, false);
        remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_CURRENT_VERSION, "1.0");
        remoteConfigDefaults.put(ForceUpdateChecker.KEY_UPDATE_URL,
                "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+getPackageName());

        firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);
        firebaseRemoteConfig.fetch(10) // fetch every minutes
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "remote config is fetched.");
                            firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: try to use [`setDefaultsAsync(Map<String, Object> defaults)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-taskvoid-setdefaultsasync-mapstring,-object-defaults) instead

Comment: yes it works, one problem gone, i fix the other my self.

Comment: How do you fix the error of "firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaults);`

with

`firebaseRemoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(remoteConfigDefaults);`

And `firebaseRemoteConfig.activateFetched();`

with

`firebaseRemoteConfig.activate();`

See below for more info -
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#public-taskvoid-setdefaultsasync-mapstring,-object-defaults